# Machine Learning Services 2017 - Unable to launch the ( python ) runtime. ErrorCode 0x80070057: 87(The parameter is incorrect.)

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, sql-server-2017

We changed over our SQL server 2017 with Machine learning Services ( MLS ) from running R 3.3.3 and Python 3.5.2 - to R 3.5.2 and Python 3.7.1.

SQL 2017 CU22 installs the higher value of R & Python, so you then have to run an exe to tell SQL to use the higher R & Python versions that were installed on disk via CU22.

After this was done successfully, when we went to restart Python we got the error :

```
Msg 39021, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Unable to launch runtime for 'Python' script. Please check the configuration of the 'Python' runtime.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
An external script error occurred: 
Unable to launch the runtime. ErrorCode 0x80070057: 87(The parameter is incorrect.).
```

This is a problem description and placeholder for the solution below.

See below for a solution that worked successfully .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look inside

E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.< instance >\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog in the pythonlauncher.lor or rlauncher.log files, you may see a line that looks similar to this :

```
 [0000293C][00002B9C][Error] Session creation failed with: F
```

This is I think is the attempt by SQL 2017 MLS to write to disk.

The fix that worked for us :

(1) Create a new directory e.g. D:\MLSTEMP

(2) Create subdirectories D:\MLSTEMP\ < SQL_instance >00 and D:\MLSTEMP\ < SQL_instance >01

** Make sure you create all 21 directories < SQL_instance >00 to < SQL_instance >20 (inclusive) - or you will be limited to only one user at a time being able to run R / Python code on a box. **

(3) Make sure the local MSSQLLaunchpad service, Everyone group & SQL service account has full access to both the D:\MLSTEMP and the sub dirs.

Note : the < > brackets are not part of the directory name

Note: launchpad service name is : NTService\MSSQLLaunchpad$ < instance_name >

(4) Go to your

D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL001\MSSQL\Binn\pythonlauncher.config

and

D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL001\MSSQL\Binn\rlauncher.config
files,

and alter the WORKING_DIRECTORY setting in each file to be WORKING_DIRECTORY=D:\MLSTEMP

(5) Restart the MSSQLLaunchpad service on the box.

Interestingly, the ****01 directory is the one that's used, not the ****00 dir.

To get more detailed info in the rlauncher or pythonlauncher log files, in the rlauncher or pythonlauncher.config files, change the trace_level setting to 4 i.e. TRACE_LEVEL=4. Its normally set to 1.

It should now work. You may have to play with permissions a bit.

HTH someone....

Comment: This answer is very helpful (thank you!), but also see my answer for a simpler way - no need to create 21 new folders, just grant permissions where needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue.

1. Go to: ...\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog folder and open pythonlauncher.log.
   (note: if you have MSSQL13 and MSSQL14 folders: check both!)

At the end of the file there is a record similar to: [Error] Session creation failed with: Failed with 2 to get security for C:\ProgramData\MSSQLSERVER\Temp-PY\MSSQLSERVER01

- this indicates an issue with permissions.

2. Go to: C:\ProgramData\MSSQLSERVER and grant everyone permissons on the Temp-PY shortcut (might not be necessarly everyone, but I'm not sure which exact user)
3. Restart SQL Server Launchpad service.

It worked for me :)

Comment: Hi, we found that if we didnt create at least 2 or more folders, it stopped more than 1 user being able to use the system at the same time.